# Does the NTSB ever not follow up a preliminary report?

Tags: accident-investigation

Two years ago, there was a fatal crash in Fredericksburg, VA in which 6 people died in a Beech 95-B55. For some reason, the story struck me, and I wrote a note to myself to follow up on it.

The NTSB published a preliminary report 12 days after the crash (on 8/24/2016) but has not published any report since then. Do investigations sometimes end at preliminary reports, or will they someday follow up with a final report?

The NTSB case is [ERA16FA288](https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20160812X50604). I searched the NTSB's "[Aviation Accident Database & Synopses](https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx)" page for all events in Virginia on 8/12/2016 (as well as googling the airplane's tail number), and couldn't find anything after that preliminary report.

Comment: Yes, there are many cases where the NTSB doesn't release a "final" report. There are also cases where the NTSB doesn't release a final report for years. You could try to contact the Richmond FSDO to ask about a status.

Comment: Looks like the final report was published Oct 1, 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a retired NTSB employee, I can say that reports with an FA number like that one should definitely close out with a probable cause determination, typically within a year.  Two years is an outlier, and the delay is likely attracting some internal attention.  If you really want to find out about the status, you can call 202-314-6290 and ask for the Ashburn field office.  It's probably their case, and the manager should be able to figure out what's holding it up.